# easy way to automatically retrieve image for desktop background?

Tags: powershell, cron, wget

I would like to automatically download and replace an image from the NASA website to use as my desktop.

in linux i used a cron job to do this, using wget to retrieve the file and a small utility to update the desktop background. cron allowed me to do this at 6 hour intervals( the update times for the SOHO images).

is there an easy way to do the same thing in win 7?

Comment: I would probably use [Wallpaper Changer Command Line Utility](http://sg20.com/techblog/2011/06/23/wallpaper-changer-command-line-utility/) and [wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) to make a small script to run as a [scheduled task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can for example use NASA's image of the day rss feed as a wallpaper (it will download the new image automatically). Just copy/paste this in plain text file with the `.theme` extension :

```
[Theme]
DisplayName=Nasa
[Slideshow]
Interval=1800000
Shuffle=1
RssFeed=http://www.nasa.gov/rss/lg_image_of_the_day.rss
[Control Panel\Desktop]
TileWallpaper=0
WallpaperStyle=0
Pattern=
[Control Panel\Cursors]
AppStarting=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_working.ani
Arrow=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_arrow.cur
Crosshair=
Hand=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_link.cur
Help=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_helpsel.cur
IBeam=
No=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_unavail.cur
NWPen=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_pen.cur
SizeAll=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_move.cur
SizeNESW=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_nesw.cur
SizeNS=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_ns.cur
SizeNWSE=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_nwse.cur
SizeWE=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_ew.cur
UpArrow=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_up.cur
Wait=%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_busy.ani
DefaultValue=Windows Aero
Link=
[VisualStyles]
Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles
ColorStyle=NormalColor
Size=NormalSize
ColorizationColor=0X6B74B8FC
Transparency=1
[MasterThemeSelector]
MTSM=DABJDKT
```

as you can see here the interesting line is

```
RssFeed=http://www.nasa.gov/rss/lg_image_of_the_day.rss
```

you can use any RSS feed you want.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Windows' equivalent of `cron` is Task Scheduler. You can create a script to download the file (it can use cygwin so you can even use `wget`) and set it to run every 6 hours using the Scheduled Tasks control panel.